# How to use CRC32?

Tags: java, crc32

When I read this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html
There is method to get CRC32 value from array of bytes. However, when I send this CRC32ed value to receiver, how can receiver check if this value is valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that the receiver will run the same algorithm on the data you sent through, and it should get the *same* CRC32 value. If not, the data (or CRC) has been corrupted somehow.

In other words, let's say your payload is `"Pax is an incredibly handsome guy"` and you calculate the CRC as 42.

You send through both that payload and the CRC to the receiving end and it performs the same actions on the payload, also coming up with 42.

That means the content of that payload is correct. But not necessarily the veracity :-)

That's what CRC stands for, cyclic redundancy **check.**

---

Keep in mind that CRCs tend to be effective against *accidental* damage to payload but, unless there's some secret information being used to generate the check, it can be faked.

Comment: There is a big caveat: CRC32 is really only reliable for detecting accidental corruption. It's a lousy choice if you're trying to detect tampering. Even SHA256 isn't enough, there, without it being used in a signature. CRC32's major selling point is it's fast.

Comment: @David, yes, _any_ known algorithm with known input (message and any keys used to make the metadata) can be faked. Digital signatures work because there is hidden info (the private key, for example). If you separate the message and the CRC and keep control of the CRC (such as publishing it on your safe website, like MD5SUMs for ISOs), it's safer. Not _totally_ safe since there's still ways to generate arbitrary messages giving the same CRC, but it's harder. You can make it harder still by using CRC _and_ message length as the signature. But, you're right, without a secret, it can be faked.

Comment: But I'll add the caveat for completeness :-)